# Applying settings in Spring based application in runtime

Tags: spring, configuration, settings, spring.net

We have Spring based (Spring.NET) web application and use VariablePlaceholderConfigurer to keep some settings in a separate properties file.
These properties are mainly different values affecting business logic, like emails, timeouts, paths, etc.
Now we need to implement administrative UI to allow users to change these settings in more friendly way.
So we will move all these settings to a database.

**Question:** What is the best (standard, common) approach to implementing settings like I described in Spring based application? (Assuming we want changes to be effective immediately without application restart.)

It is good if we can keep our current approach when setting values as just properties of beans.

Answer (score 0):

The [`VariablePlaceholderConfigurer`](http://www.springframework.net/docs/1.3.0-RC1/api/net-2.0/html/Spring.Core~Spring.Objects.Factory.Config.VariablePlaceholderConfigurer.html) is [`ObjectFactoryPostProcessor`](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-customizing-factory-postprocessors), which is only invoked after reading the object definitions. So you cannot simply introduce a new `IVariableSource` that you refer to in your `VariablePlaceholderConfigurer` configuration, because it will only take effect after container reload.

You have to create an [`IObjectObjectPostProcessor`](http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/objects.html#objects-factory-customizing) to modify properties on container managed objects at runtime.